Why do Staging Ground posts asking for edits get "graduated" to the main site automatically?
Why do Staging Ground posts asking for edits get "graduated" to the main site automatically?
For example: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79261289
It had two requests for "Minor Edits", but the history shows those requests are also marked as approvals, and so the post graduated to the main site automatically after 2 days of no edits being made.
Is this correct design?


This is indeed the way the system is designed to work. There's  probably a larger conversation to be had about whether this is the way we would like the system to work. There's also probably a conversation to be had about whether the "minor edits" option has clear guidance for usage. But as far as this question is concerned, the system is working as designed and as documented through the betas and in the help centre.

Documented... Pshaw! If you want to hide something around here you put it in the documentation. No one reads the documentation.

Regarding "guidance for usage", we're using Meta to address that.

@user4581301 I read the documentation. Specifically the help centre and it was wrong as the answer points out. The documented behaviour by a user was correct. The "during the beta" is also correct if you read very carefully this entire post from 2 years ago or less carefully (more directly states minor edits will be published automatically) this one, also from 2 years ago. I went through every single post about staging ground minor edits on Meta and found only the two. This Q&A provides a third.

You can't win either way. People don't read... and the people that do read first have to themselves write correct documentation to read. It's just not memetic when it comes to Stack Overflow. It's only sad.

Yes, this seems to be as designed. The option is called "Conditionally approve with Minor edits". This means the question is approved, and any edit will publish it. Even if the author does not change the question, it is graduated after 24h.
The help center is slightly misleading. It states:

Conditionally approve with minor edits: This option indicates that the post is nearly ready, but needs simple tweaks or changes before it goes live. This option requires the asker to revise their post before it is posted.

The user created reviewers guide is actually correct, and gives additional guidance (emphasis mine):

Use "Minor Edits" sparingly
The "Conditionally approve pending minor edits" option allows the author to publish the question as soon as they make an edit to their question (or it is automatically published if the author doesn't edit it within 24h), no matter how meaningless that edit is. Only use this option if you think the question is ok to be published as-is but there is something where the author could still improve it.
If the author needs to make a change (even if it is just a small change) before the question can be published, use the "Requires Major Changes" option instead.


As a side note, the timeline shows both "approved" and "requested minor edit" when using the "Minor Edits" option.
